# TCP connection to windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, tcp, connection, port, virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM that I can't connect to. I have done the following steps. What am I missing here?

1. Created an endpoint (port 1431) in the portal
2. Created a rule for port 1431 in the firewall on the VM
3. Started a server (TCP Test Tool) that is listening on port 1431
4. Tried to connect locally with a client (port 1431) on the VM - Works as expected.
5. Tried to connect remotely to the VM - FAILS

If I try to telnet port 3389 (rdp) it works fine.

I have restarted the machine.

Any ideas?

Thanx
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the both the public endpoint port and private endpoint port are set to 1431.

In addition, test to make sure you setup your firewall rule correctly. An easy way to do this is to temporarily disable the firewall. Can you connect if you do this? If so your rule is not configured correctly.

Also, what do you mean you "can't connect" being that RDP works?

Lastly, try a different port number and see if it works.

[image]

Comment: Thanx for answering! I have done all these tests. Didn't try to turn off firewall though. Will try that to see if it is the firewall that is blocking. RDP works fine. Also the common ports like 80 and 8080.

Comment: Turning off the firewall had no effect. I tried to open a new "common" port (443) and that worked well. Tried again to open a new "not common" port (444) and it did not work. It seems that only common ports are allowed?!

Comment: How are you testing connectivity to port 444? You can set an endpoint for any port, not just "common" ports. I just tested again on one of my VM's and it worked great. A simple way to test it is to create a new site in IIS and bind it to that port. Also, maybe try a higher up port like 3000 and see if that works. I am sure we can figure this out!

Comment: So embarrasing. I tested from another location and it worked. It seems I'm not able to connect from my current location. Firewall is blocking me. I will accept your answer and consider another career :(

Comment: No worries it happens to the best of us! I'm just glad you were able to figure it out.